# Why height animation with display: none are isn't working?

Tags: html, css

I try to figure out with css animation, but faced to this issue.

I did the height animation with `@keyframes` `from 0px to size` and it's working, but if I want to revert animation `from size to 0px` and add `display: none` to parent element it isn't working. So display trigger earlier than animation did?

Do you have some advice how to resolve task like that through css?

Code

```js
$('.toggle-nav').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $('nav').toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.toggle-nav {
  padding: 7px 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #fff;
}
nav li {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  animation: slide-down-list-revert .3s linear 0s;
}
nav {
  display: none;
}
nav.active {
  display: block;
}
nav.active li {
  display: block;
  animation: slide-down-list .3s linear 0s;
}

@keyframes slide-down-list {
  from {
    height: 0;
  }
  to {
    height: 30px;
  }
}
@keyframes slide-down-list-revert {
  from {
    height: 30px;
  }
  to {
    height: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="toggle-nav" href="#">&#9776;</a>
<nav>
  <ul>
     <li><a>Item 1</a></li>
     <li><a>Item 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Also my code is here: https://jsfiddle.net/guar47/w6o8a52b/11/

Comment: can you please provide code here coz your jsfiddle code is not working

Comment: Yes display is triggered immediately why would it wait for the animation ends? Also, note that it can't be animated.

Comment: Fixed link and added code to post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the way you have written it, the element will be hidden before your animation even begins. If you want to revert the visible state of the `nav li`, you *first* need to complete the animation and *then* hide it. This can be done by adding an `animationend` event to the `nav` or `nav li` and handler can hide it as soon as the `animationend` is fired.

I've rewritten something to that effect. Note that I added another class to your CSS called `revert` which runs your `slide-down-list-revert` animation.

```js
$('.toggle-nav').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var nav = $('nav');
  if(!nav.hasClass('active')){
    nav.toggleClass('active');
  }
  else{
    nav.addClass('revert');
  }
});

$('nav').on('animationend', function(){
  if ($(this).hasClass('revert')){
    $('nav').toggleClass('revert active');
  }
});
```

```css
.toggle-nav {
  padding: 7px 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #fff;
}
nav li {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  animation: slide-down-list-revert .3s linear 0s;
}
nav {
  display: none;
}
nav.active {
  display: block;
}
nav.active li {
  display: block;
  animation: slide-down-list .3s linear 0s;
}
nav.revert li{
  animation: slide-down-list-revert .3s linear 0s;
}

@keyframes slide-down-list {
  from {
    height: 0;
  }
  to {
    height: 30px;
  }
}
@keyframes slide-down-list-revert {
  from {
    height: 30px;
  }
  to {
    height: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="toggle-nav" href="#">&#9776;</a>
<nav>
  <ul>
     <li><a>Item 1</a></li>
     <li><a>Item 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to replace your code with below code:

```
$('.toggle-nav').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('nav').slideToggle();
});
```

Then remove other CSS that you are using for animation.